# Could not find google-play-services_lib_r29.apk

Tags: android, eclipse

When I'm about to run my project as an Android application they send me this message:

> Could not find google-play-services_lib_r29.apk

I tried many solutions but I have the same error:

```
[2016-11-04 00:12:28 - google-play-services_lib_r29] Could not find google-play-services_lib_r29.apk!
[2016-11-04 00:12:28 - HoppingBird] Starting activity com.titanzrobinrun.game.MainActivity on device xxxxxxxxxx
[2016-11-04 00:12:28 - HoppingBird] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.titanzrobinrun.game/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Did your phone have google-play-services? If not, try to download it and run your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check refenced libraries you need to remove the project 
 google-play-services_lib.jar

```
Project -> Properties -> javaBuildPath -> Project- > Select google-play-services-> Remove.
```

Just 1 step more, Clean and Build.

Comment: Select this answer like the correct  then for another people. @BUZZ24HD